# Java NullPointerException with truncated stacktrace

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

I am getting following failure for my RabbitMQ listner.
I use Spring Boot 1.4.1  with Spring integration 4.3.3 (with spring-boot-starter-amqp and spring-integration-amqp). I also use RabbitMQ 3.5.7.

Issue occurs for small number of messages, randomly under significant traffic (non luck reproducing it sofar locally).

What puzzles me is the fact that stack trace does not point to my application, just to frameworks. Below I attach full stacktrace. Is it bug in spring, rabbitMQ driver or server?

```
2017-05-02 10:38:42.337 [501de2ff-cd24-4c28-8434-48bc942457d9]  WARN 1 --- [messageListenerContainer-2] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:870)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:780)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:700)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:95)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:187)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1187)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:681)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1165)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1149)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:95)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1312)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:89)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:292)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:212)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:129)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:423)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:373)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:171)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$400(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$1.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:95)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:777)
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: Would you mind showing more StackTrace after that `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null`? OTOH, please, show the Service Activator's method which processes messages.

Comment: I attached my full stacktrace. Please read my answer below how it is possible :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long investigation it turned out there is nothing wrong with Spring or rabbitMQ.  Root cause was in my own code.

Log attached to question has complete stacktrace, but java truncates stacktraces!

Java 1.5.0 introduced flag OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, enabled by default. This is performance optimization. It removes common part of stacktraces from exceptions.

In my case, I had full stacktrace for first 130 occurences of this exception. Further occurences had stacktrace truncated. Easiest way to get full stacktrace was to restart  the application.

See http://jawspeak.com/2010/05/26/hotspot-caused-exceptions-to-lose-their-stack-traces-in-production-and-the-fix/ for details.